# Can't connect with Web Map Services - problem with OpenSSL 3.0.2 Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: qgis-3, wms, pyqt5, ssl, ssl-error

This problem is connected with Qt5 I believe, starting QGIS from the command line gives, amongst many other messages:

```
Warning: Incompatible version of OpenSSL
Warning: QSslSocket: cannot call unresolved function d2i_X509
Warning: QSslSocket::connectToHostEncrypted: TLS initialization failed.
```

The desktop looks like this when trying to connect to a WMS server:

[image: QGIS 3.34.1 can't connect to WMS]

Comment: Please paste the error message as text rather a screenshot.

Comment: OK, sorry, I thought a small screenshot may help, in case anyone else has had a similar problem.

Comment: A solution here maybe?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58625924/qt-error-message-qt-network-ssl-qsslsocketconnecttohostencrypted-tls-initia

Comment: On my machine `openssl version` gives `OpenSSL 3.0.2 15 Mar 2022 (Library: OpenSSL 3.0.2 15 Mar 2022)` and I have no WMS issues with `QGIS version 3.34.1-Prizren Qt version 5.15.3`

Comment: Ian, is yours a Windows machine? I'm using Ubuntu 22.04. I suspect that the Qt5 libraries used for the latest QGIS  build can only cope with OpenSSL 1.1, on my setup. But I don't know for sure.

Comment: In QGIS under settings then options, there is a Network section with parameters that can be set for proxy etc, and in the WMS connection itself, there are the authentication options and other configs. I believe that a configuration in those locations would clear this up. I saw it in the past, but can't recall what I did to correct it. I don't think it has to do with Ubuntu, but the WMS or Network connection, parms.

Comment: Thanks, I've tried that and still get the "TLS initialization failed" response. I can test the same link with JOSM (OpenStreetMap editing software), on the same PC and there's no problem with getting data from WMS urls. JOSM is a Java app, so authentication is different,

Comment: On my Ubuntu 22.04 machine `openssl version` gives OpenSSL 3.0.2 15 Mar 2022 (Library: OpenSSL 3.0.2 15 Mar 2022) and I have no WMS issues with QGIS version 3.34.1-Prizren Qt version 5.15.3. I suggest you check the url.

Comment: Thanks, but I've checked - the urls are fine. Apart from WMS, QGIS version information and access to the plugin repository not working properly either. With identical QGIS and OpenSSL versions, my only question is 'did you build QGIS from source? I used a package manager.

Comment: I've fixed it, fairly simple in the end: export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ ;and then:sudo ldconfig. File paths needed by QGIS for libssl.so.3 and libcrypto.so.3 (OpenSSL)

Answer (score 0):

As I have spent a long time sorting this out, in my case the problem was fixed by removing an old symlink linking `/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.1.1` to `/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so`. Removing (deleting) the link `/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so` fixed it for me (I don't know where the link came from, or if removing it broke anything else). In a separate machine this link is not there and causes no problems (both Debian 11).

(not posted as a comment, as I don't have enough reputation)